# Why cant I see the icon?

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot see any issues with my code, although I cannot see the icon as shown in the picture. I'm just starting dart, so I would appreciate an answer.

```dart
ElevatedButton.icon(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.deepOrange[700],
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.mail,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  label: Text('Mail me'),
),
```

[image]

Comment: try `fluter clean` and rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

```
ElevatedButton.icon(

      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  primary: Colors.deepOrange[700],
  ),
  onPressed: () {},


  icon: Icon(
  Icons.mail,
  color: Colors.white,


  ),
  label: Text('Mail me'),

  )
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not seeing the icon though. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: I did it. Turns out my pubspec.yaml file was corrupt!